# Why does a layer-like structure occurs in a cold plasma? See pictures

Tags: plasma-physics

I've been experimenting with cold plasma created by a high voltage source at a frequency of about 23kHz. I observed that sometimes the plasma forms layers within the bulk plasma. Following picture shows what I've observed. Could you explain why this occurs?

[image]

[image]

Comment: These layers form in the air under what conditions?

Comment: It's not air. It's plasma. Ionized gas. This was formed under 23kHz high voltage signal under the pressure range of 500-1000 milliTorr. The voltage is around 20kV with a current of about 60 mA.

Comment: What kind of gas is this?

Comment: It is Argon gas.

Comment: It looks like a stratified glow discharge, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge#/media/File:Glow_discharge_regions.jpg . If you describe the dimensions of the camera, then we can calculate these luminous layers.

Comment: Thank you! Dimensions of the camera are 12.8 MP, resolution 4128x3096, pixel size :1.09 um, focal lenght: 3.71mm, 35m equivalent focal length: 28.3mm, field of view: 63 degrees Horizontal, crop factor: 7.6x.

Comment: And how many frames are there per second?

Comment: 30 frames per second. The camera is Samsung Galaxy J7 Max main camera.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is due to a standing wave.  You could test this by moving the electrodes closer together and seeing if the layers move closer together.  The layers are too close together to represent 25kHz waves, but could possibly represent a high harmonic of a 25kHz fundamental.